# type error while parsing json output python

Tags: python, json, subprocess, whmcs

i'm trying to parse some fields of a json, that is an output for a command line. but i can't access to any field, i've always this error :

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

my json output is like this :

```
{"result":"success","totalresults":"1","startnumber":0,"numreturned":1,"tickets":{
    "ticket":[
        {
        "id":"2440",
        "tid":"473970",
        "deptid":"1",
        "userid":"0",
        "name":"John",
        "email":"email@email.it",
        "cc":"","c":"P1gqiLym",
        "date":"2016-07-01 13:00:02",
        "subject":"test",
        "status":"stato",
        "priority":"Medium",
        "admin":"",
        "attachment":"image001.jpg",
        "lastreply":"",
        "flag":"0",
        "service":""
        }
    ]
}
}
```

and my code is this :

```
import json
import sys
import subprocess

output=subprocess.call('pywhmcs --url http://whmcs.test.it --username myuser --password mypass --action gettickets --params status="tickets" email="email@email.com"',shell=True)
values = json.loads(str(output))
print (values['result'])
```

why i can't access to any fields? maybe i cannot parse this type of subprocess output?

thanks guys

Comment: Don't you mean `print(values['result'])` ? And subprocess.call returns an int, this is not the way to get your json string.

Comment: ops sorry you're right, but i've same error.
well i try also os.system but same error...i try to cast to string

Comment: Check the output ? And make sure that it's having proper response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `subprocess.call` returns the *resultcode* of the execution; which is either 0 (if successful) or any other positive integer if there is an error condition.

Now, when you execute `output['result']`, it is the same as doing `0['result']` which doesn't make sense as numbers don't support fetching by `[]`, the technical term for that is `__getitem__`.

You need to execute `subprocess.check_output`; which returns the output as a string.

Then you have another minor issue that you need to fetch the dictionary on the resulting parsed json, and not `output`.

In short, you need:

```
import json
# import sys -- not required
import subprocess

output=subprocess.check_output('pywhmcs --url http://whmcs.test.it --username myuser --password mypass --action gettickets --params status="tickets" email="email@email.com"',shell=True)
values = json.loads(str(output))
print (values['result']) # note values, not output
```

Comment: But the output contains the shell prompt on the first line when using `shell=True` so the JSON is broken. How is it possible it's working for you? Do you have any idea how to omit the prompt from the output, please?

Comment: OK, got it. It contains the prompt only when run on a Windows machine, on a Linux one, the output contains only the output of the command being executed. Do you know how to make it work also on Windows systems, please?